# why introducing date parameter messes up my query? 3 tables JOIN in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, magento-1.9

Writing a report that will return 3 columns

1. list of all simple products
2. current stock levels against each product
3. sold qty in specified period against each product. If no sales, then show zero.

```
sku       | qty | sold qty    
product 1 | 5   | 15    
product 2 | 7   | 0    
product 3 | 0   | 15    
product 4 | 0   | 0
```

Code works as intended when not specifying a date period. However, that gives me entire sales history. I want to see sales history for, say, last month, quarter, year.

When specifying a period using above line it skips SKUs that had no sales in specified period.

```
sku       | qty | sold qty    
product 1 | 5   | 15    
product 3 | 0   | 15
```

I would like to see all SKUs, including those with zero sales.

```
SELECT 
    p.sku,
    FORMAT(s.qty, 0) AS qty,
    IFNULL(FORMAT(SUM(o.qty_invoiced), 0), 0) AS 'sold qty'
FROM
    mage_catalog_product_entity AS p
        LEFT JOIN
    mage_cataloginventory_stock_item AS s ON p.entity_id = s.product_id
        LEFT JOIN
    mage_sales_flat_order_item AS o ON p.entity_id = o.product_id
WHERE
    p.type_id = 'simple' 
       AND o.created_at BETWEEN '2018-11-01 00:00:01' AND '2019-01-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY p.sku
ORDER BY SUM(o.qty_invoiced) DESC;
```

I would like to see all SKUs in column 1, including those with zero sales. It does that when looking at entire sales history and not specifying a date period. Not sure how adding a date period in the mix changes the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is to move the condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT p.sku,
       FORMAT(SUM(s.qty), 0) AS qty,
       COALESCE(FORMAT(SUM(o.qty_invoiced), 0), 0) AS `sold qty`
FROM mage_catalog_product_entity p LEFT JOIN
     mage_cataloginventory_stock_item s
     ON p.entity_id = s.product_id LEFT JOIN
     mage_sales_flat_order_item o
     ON p.entity_id = o.product_id AND
        o.created_at >= '2018-11-01' AND
        o.created_at < '2019-02-01'
WHERE p.type_id = 'simple' 
GROUP BY p.sku;
```

The key change is moving the condition on the date into the `ON` clause.  That way, it doesn't turn the outer join into an inner join.

Other changes:

- Note the change to the date arithmetic.  Don't use `between` with dates.  In this case, it is just messy and misses two seconds out of the day -- which I imagine is not intentional.
- I much prefer `COALESCE()` instead of `IFNULL()` because `COALESCE()` is standard SQL.
- Something needs to be done with `s.qty`.  Either include it in the `GROUP BY` or use an aggregation function.  I chose the latter, not knowing what the data looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition on `o.created_at` in your `WHERE` clause is converting the `LEFT JOIN` to `mage_sales_flat_order_item` into an `INNER JOIN`. To fix that, move

```
AND o.created_at BETWEEN '2018-11-01 00:00:01' AND '2019-01-31 23:59:59'
```

out of the `WHERE` clause and into the `ON` clause for the `LEFT JOIN` to `mage_sales_flat_order_item`